# Sizes of training set and test set

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-analysis

What happens when the training set is smaller than test set for a particular case. What would be the suitable approaches when predicting using those type of data sets. Can anyone give me some introduction on to manage those situations and how each learning algorithm would perform.

Answer (score 2):

What is your concern? What bad to you *expect* to arise from that? Too much verification? Overvalidation?

The test set is not involved in training the classifier.

It only serves the purpose of allowing you to *predict the quality of your classifier* for future data.

So if you have a large test set, you will probably get a better prediction of the quality of your classifier, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

One solution when you have a small training set and large test set is instead to combine the sets and use k-fold cross validation. But, ideally you'd accumulate a larger training set. Beware of using out-of-the-box machine learning on ill-suited problems.